# Powershell - Prefix each line of Format-Table with String

Tags: powershell, formatting

I would like to know if there is an easy way of prefixing each line of a powershell table with a String.

For example, if I create an Array using the following code:

```
$Array = @()  
$Object = @{}  
$Object.STR_PARAM = "A"  
$Object.INT_PARAM = 1  
$Array += [PSCustomObject] $Object  
$Object = @{}  
$Object.STR_PARAM = "B"  
$Object.INT_PARAM = 2  
$Array += [PSCustomObject] $Object
```

Calling `Format-Table` give the following output:

```
$Array | Format-Table -AutoSize  

STR_PARAM INT_PARAM
--------- ---------
A                 1
B                 2
```

Instead, I would like to have the following:

```
$Array | Format-Table-Custom -AutoSize -PrefixString "  "

  STR_PARAM INT_PARAM
  --------- ---------
  A                 1
  B                 2
```

And if possible, I would also like to be able to use the `Property` parameter like this:

```
$SimpleFormat = @{Expression={$_.STR_PARAM}; Label="String Param"},
                @{Expression={$_.INT_PARAM}; Label="Integer Param"};

$Array | Format-Table-Custom -Property $SimpleFormat -AutoSize -PrefixString "++"

++String Param Integer Param
++------------ -------------
++A                        1
++B                        2
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the format expressions directly:

```
$f = @{Expression={"++" + $_.STR_PARAM}; Label="++String Param"},
     @{Expression={$_.INT_PARAM}; Label="Integer Param"};
$Array | Format-Table $f -AutoSize
```

Output

```
++String Param Integer Param
-------------- -------------
++A                        1
++B                        2
```

**Update to use expression and filter**

```
Filter Format-Table-Custom
{
    Param
    (
        [string]
        $PrefixString,
        [object]
        $Property
    )
    end {
        $rows = $input | Format-Table $property -AutoSize | Out-String
        $lines = $rows.Split("`n")
        foreach ($line in $lines) {
            if ($line.Trim().Length -gt 0) {
                $PrefixString + $line
            }
        }
    }
}

$f = @{Expression={"--" + $_.STR_PARAM}; Label="--String Param"},
     @{Expression={$_.INT_PARAM}; Label="Integer Param"};
$Array | Format-Table-Custom -Property $f -PrefixString "++"
```

Output

```
++--String Param Integer Param
++-------------- -------------
++--A                        1
++--B                        2
```

Comment: Almost perfect. Would you be able to replace the first 2 `--` with `++`?

Comment: Not directly with that approach, but should be possible with filter or function. i'll give it a shot

Comment: Just updated answer with filter that seems to do what you're asking